# I'm passing SYSIN from PDS member and in Cobol program I am the value using Accept variable from SYSIN giving U4038 error

Tags: cobol, jcl

I got the below error when trying to read the input value using SYSIN from PDS member.

```
//SYSIN DD DSN=SYSGEN.DEVL.GBUYVC.GDPR.CODE(PFMA342X),DISP=SHR
```

And in Cobol I mentioned below accept statement:

```
ACCEPT W-QUOTE-CURRENT-YEAR FROM SYSIN.
```

I got the below error when I submitted the job

> Error: open of DISPLAY or ACCEPT file with environment name SYSIN was
>   unsuccessful.

Can someone help me understand where I am doing mistake?

Comment: IBM mainframe forum can be another best place to look into http://www.ibmmainframeforum.com/jcl/ . It is a subjective opinion though

Comment: What is your working storage definition of W-QUOTE-CURRENT-YEAR? And what are the dataset charactefristics of your input dataset?

Comment: We need to see the JESJOBLG output, There should be a message in there that will tell us what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thanks for taking time and giving your valuable inputs.

Actually in JCL I was using a Proc that does not accept SYSIN so i removed that PROC and simply executed the JCL like

```
//STEP01 EXEC PGM=progname,
//SYSIN DD DSN=Datasetname,DISP=SHR
```

This way it worked

Comment: Was this mentioned in the original question?  What were you asking then?